# How can I react to event on system variable defined in CAPL script?

Tags: var, sys, capl, system-variable, canalyzer

I defined a system variable in my CAPL file that I use to set up different modes in my script.
I declared it in my CAPL file and not in my CANAlyzer window in order to allow the script to work with differents config.

```
sysDefineNamespace("NameSpace");

sysDefineVariableInt("NameSpace","VariableName",0);
```

The declaration has worked because I can change the value of this system variable with on key events.

The problem is with on sysvar events, the synthax that I saw on internet is not working. I use this one :

```
on sysvar NameSpace::VariableName{
  sysSetVariableInt("NameSpace","VariableName",0); //init tout Ã  off
}
```

I have a compilation error :

```
Compiling...
  Options: CANalyzer, Realtime
Name (1, 11) Error 1249: Variable name 'NameSpace' not found
Compilation errors.
```

I'm pretty sure it is a synthax error but I didn't manage to fix it.

Thank you for your help !

I tried to change the synthax several time without success.

Comment: AFAIK the event handler `on sysvar` can only be used with system variables that are defined at compile-time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
So I guess I can only use it with system variable that were defined in my CANalyzer .cfg file?

Comment: Exactly. That is my understanding. System variables created at runtime, i.e. via CAPL can only be used to hold data, but `on sysvar` events will not be triggered.